# Delete Specific value from redis hash field value

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cli

I have redis hash, i want to delete the specific value of field.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset abc 12 34,121
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall abc
1) "12"
2) "34,121"
```

I only want to delete 121 from value.

I know hdel command deletes the field but not specific value of field.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hdel abc 12
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall abc
(empty array)
```

this deletes the whole field for hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes in Redis store Redis Strings. Redis has no idea that the value contains a comma-separated list of number. It just sees a String. You'll need to pull the value out, modify it in code, then write it back in.

If you want to do this atomically, you'll need to look at using [transactions](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/)— which give you an optimistic locking mechanism—or write a Lua script. Here's how to do it with a transaction.

First, WATCH the key `abc`. If during the transaction this key is changed, the transaction will fail and you'll need to handle it in your code.

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> WATCH abc
OK
```

Now you need to fetch the value of the field from the key and write code to parse it and remove the offending value:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET abc 12
"34,121"
```

To write the value out and make sure that nobody else has done the same, start a transaction using MULTI, HSET the new value for the field, and call EXEC:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> HSET abc 12 34
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> EXEC
1) (integer) 0
```

If nobody has changed `abc`, EXEC should return the results of the commands that you have queued, in this case the number of fields that were added to the Hash. If somebody *has* changed the key `abc` that it will return `(nil)` instead and you'll need to try again in your code.

If it's an option, you might want to consider using [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) to store these values as JSON in Redis instead. Then, you could simply modify the array using JSONPath queries:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET abc $ '{ "12": [ 34, 121 ]}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.DEL abc "$.12[?(@ == 121)]"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET abc
"{\"12\":[34]}"
```

Easier to code and no need to mess about with transactions or Lua.